# Issues while importing imblearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, python-import, imblearn

I am trying to import SMOTE in my jupyter notebook.I tried the following steps;

I first installed imblearn using the following command in my terminal

```
conda install -c glemaitre imbalanced-learn
```

Then i used the following command to import imblearn in my notebook;

```
from imblearn import under_sampling, over_sampling
```

I am getting the following error;

```
    <ipython-input-36-d0524665b8f2> in <module>()
----> 1 from imblearn import under_sampling, over_sampling

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imblearn/under_sampling/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 """
      5 
----> 6 from .prototype_generation import ClusterCentroids
      7 
      8 from .prototype_selection import RandomUnderSampler

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imblearn/under_sampling/prototype_generation/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 """
      5 
----> 6 from .cluster_centroids import ClusterCentroids
      7 
      8 __all__ = [

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imblearn/under_sampling/prototype_generation/cluster_centroids.py in <module>()
     12 from scipy import sparse
     13 
---> 14 from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
     15 from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
     16 from sklearn.utils import safe_indexing

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 """
      5 
----> 6 from .spectral import spectral_clustering, SpectralClustering
      7 from .mean_shift_ import (mean_shift, MeanShift,
      8                           estimate_bandwidth, get_bin_seeds)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/spectral.py in <module>()
     15 from ..metrics.pairwise import pairwise_kernels
     16 from ..neighbors import kneighbors_graph
---> 17 from ..manifold import spectral_embedding
     18 from .k_means_ import k_means
     19 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 
      5 from .locally_linear import locally_linear_embedding, LocallyLinearEmbedding
----> 6 from .isomap import Isomap
      7 from .mds import MDS, smacof
      8 from .spectral_embedding_ import SpectralEmbedding, spectral_embedding

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/isomap.py in <module>()
      9 from ..utils import check_array
     10 from ..utils.graph import graph_shortest_path
---> 11 from ..decomposition import KernelPCA
     12 from ..preprocessing import KernelCenterer
     13 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/__init__.py in <module>()
      9 from .incremental_pca import IncrementalPCA
     10 from .kernel_pca import KernelPCA
---> 11 from .sparse_pca import SparsePCA, MiniBatchSparsePCA
     12 from .truncated_svd import TruncatedSVD
     13 from .fastica_ import FastICA, fastica

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/sparse_pca.py in <module>()
      9 from ..utils import check_random_state, check_array
     10 from ..utils.validation import check_is_fitted
---> 11 from ..linear_model import ridge_regression
     12 from ..base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
     13 from .dict_learning import dict_learning, dict_learning_online

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/__init__.py in <module>()
     10 # complete documentation.
     11 
---> 12 from .base import LinearRegression
     13 
     14 from .bayes import BayesianRidge, ARDRegression

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py in <module>()
     25 
     26 from ..externals import six
---> 27 from ..utils import Parallel, delayed
     28 from ..base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin, RegressorMixin
     29 from ..utils import check_array, check_X_y

ImportError: cannot import name 'Parallel
```

Can anyone please guide me?
Thanks!

Comment: please copy and paste the whole error stack trace. Not just that one line of error.

Comment: is it for oversampling ? I have this and it works for me: `from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE`

Comment: I am still getting an error with that.How did you install imblearn? May be I am not installing it correctly

Answer (score 0):

So it worked after I installed SMOTE using the following steps;

```
pip install -U imbalanced-learn
conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn
```

Looks like I was installing it incorrectly.

I am not able to understand the errors in the previous installation.Would appreciate if someone could point those out to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have the same issue, but I ran the following command in terminal or command prompt to fix the issue.

```
pip install -U imbalanced-learn
```

after its successfull execution i ran following conda command

```
conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn
```

that's how i fixed my problem

Comment: You'll want to update your approach for using `pip` and `conda` inside Jupyter notebooks to take advantage of the current best practices. It boils down to no longer using the exclamation point for those commands. The magic commands and `%pip install` and `%conda install` were added to make sure the installs get placed in the actual environment that backs the notebook, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more information. The use of the exclamation point alone wasn't capable of that.

Comment: Because in most modern Jupyter systems automagics are enabled by default, you can actually leave off the symbol  in front of `pip` or `conda` and get the modern magic commands used behind-the-scenes as well. In summary, use of an exclamation point inside a Jupyter notebook in combination with `pip` or `conda` is outdated.

Comment: @Wayne It seems worth putting the information in your two comments as an answer to OP's question. Future readers of this question would appreciate the information I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

Adding these comments as an answer at the suggestion of joanis:

A convenient way to install packages to the same environment backing a Jupyter notebook is to use the modern magic commands for `pip` and `conda` in cells in the notebook. The magic commands `%pip install <package name>` and `%conda install <package name>` were added to make sure the installs done inside a Jupyter notebook get placed in the actual environment that backs the notebook, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more information. The use of the exclamation point alone in front of pip or conda wasn't capable of insuring installation to the proper backing environment, and this often lead to issues of users not understanding why they couldn't import properly after they thought they had installed following the advice of others.

(The `%` symbol will work in front of `pip` and `conda` for other commands besides installs, and so it is just easiest to think of best practice for the use of pip and conda **inside Jupyter notebooks** now as `%pip ...` or `%conda ...`, where `...` represents the rest of the command.)

Because in most modern Jupyter systems automagics are enabled by default, you can actually leave off the symbol in front of pip or conda and get the modern magic commands used behind-the-scenes as well. Although it is often best to use the explicit `%` symbol so that you and others are more aware of what is happening.